# Getting "Could not resolve placeholder in string value"

Tags: spring, jboss6.x

I am using Jboss 6 for deploying the project. What i want is to have a datasource.properties file and using that file to define datasource bean. I did this but get error that "Could not resolve placeholder in string value".

My datasource.properties file is placed inside config module jboss folder.

and in my application context i have added

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:datasource.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```

This is my datasource.properties file

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mkyongjava
    jdbc.username=root
    jdbc.password=password
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Place your properties file under **src/main/resources** and try again.

=====================================

Below reference was taken from [this article.](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) which may help.

**8. Properties in Parent-Child Contexts**

This question keeps coming up again and again – what happens when you web application has a parent and a child context? The parent context may have some common core functionality and beans, and then one (or multiple) child contexts, maybe containing servlet specific beans. In that case, what’s the best way to define properties files and include them into these contexts? What’s more – how to best retrieve these properties form Spring? Here is the simple breakdown.

**8.1. If the properties file is defined in XML with**

If the file is defined in the Parent context:

@Value works in Child context: NO

@Value works in Parent context: YES

If the file is defined in the Child context:

@Value works in Child context: YES

@Value works in Parent context: NO

Finally, as we discussed before,  does not expose the properties to the environment, so:

environment.getProperty works in either context: NO

Comment: I cannot do that as config and persistence are two different module and my requirement is to place the datasource property file inside config and use it in persistence.. Thats why i am adding it to the classpath using the code abve "classpath:datasource.properties".

Comment: this article may help http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/ and this https://sethuramanmurali.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/load-properties-file-using-spring-context/

Comment: your properties file should be located in the src/main/resources

Comment: No i cannot add that property file unde src/main/resource because of some constrants. What i can do is adding the directory conf/jboss to the classpath of jboss6. But as i dont have any ide so how can i do that without using any ide?